# Printing Final Balance Out Assembly (Irvine)

Tags: assembly, irvine32

This program calculates the final balance of the user by taking user input (deposit & withdraw). The program calculates the final balance correctly but when I print it out using WriteInt from Irvine library, it prints +4218884 regardless of value final balance has. Any ideas why?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc


.data

initialBalance  DWORD 1000
finalBalance    DWORD 0

numOfDeposit    DWORD 0
numOfWithDraw   DWORD 0

msgDeposit      BYTE "How many deposit?", 0
msgWithdraw     BYTE "How many withdraw?", 0
msgEnterD       BYTE "ENTER DEPOIST: ", 0
msgEnterW       BYTE "ENTER WITHDRAW: ", 0    
msgFinalBalance BYTE "Your final balance is: ", 0

.code
main proc

mov ebx, initialBalance             ;move the initial balance to the ebx register

mov edx, OFFSET msgDeposit              ;move the address of msgDeposit to edx for printing it out
call WriteString                        ;print the msgDeposit out

call ReadInt                            ;read the number of deposits user made
mov numOfDeposit, eax                   ;store that number in umOfDeposit

mov edx, OFFSET msgWithdraw             ;move the address of msgWithdraw to eax for printing it out
call WriteString                        ;print the msgWithdraw out

call ReadInt                            ;read the number of withdraws user made
mov numOfWithdraw, eax                  ;store that number in numOfWithdraw

mov ecx, numOfDeposit                   ;sets the counter for depoLoop 


mov eax, initialBalance                 ;move initial balance to eax
add finalBalance, eax                   ;move element in eax to final balance

depositLoop:
mov edx, OFFSET msgEnterD               ;move the address of the msg, "enter deposit", to edx for print it out
call WriteString                        ;print the message out

call ReadInt                            ;read a deposit that the user made
add finalBalance, eax                   ;add the deposit to the final balance.

loop depositLoop                        ;repeat the loop

mov ecx, numOfWithDraw                  ;sets the counter for withdrawLoop

withdrawLoop:
mov edx, OFFSET msgEnterW               ;"ENTER WITHDRAW"  
call WriteString                        ;print the message out

call ReadInt                            ;read a withdraw that the user made
sub finalBalance, eax                   ;substract from final balance 

loop withdrawLoop                       ;repeat the loop


mov edx, OFFSET msgFinalBalance         ;move the address of the msg, "Your final balance is: ", to edx for printing
call WriteString                        ;print the message out

mov eax, OFFSET finalBalance            ;move the final balance to eax for printing it out
call WriteInt                           ;print the final balance out
call Crlf                               

call WaitMsg                            ;Displays a message and waits for a key to be pressed.

exit
main endp
end main
```

Comment: For printing integers, pass the value not a pointer. Instead of `mov eax, OFFSET finalBalance` do `mov eax, finalBalance`

Answer (score 2):

```
mov eax, OFFSET finalBalance            ;move the final balance to eax for printing it out
call WriteInt                           ;print the final balance out
call Crlf
```

Try:

`mov eax, finalBalance`